# How can I Print \n after each sentence?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a newbie and was trying something..

Example:

```
text = """
Hello, how are you?
I'm fine and you?
Same as always..
"""
print(text)
```

**And want this output:**

Hello, how are you? \nI'm fine and you? \nSame as always..

> Sorry if this question is silly..
> I'm newbie and was searching this for 4 days but didn't found anything related to this and finally decided to ask it on stack overflow

Comment: You want to replace an actual line break with "\n"…?

Comment: I believe you are confusing the CONTENT of the string with the REPRESENTATION of the string.  The `"\n"` sequence is just the way we write a newline in a string constant.  Your string does contain three newlines.  If you print `repr(text)`, you will see that Python shows you the newlines as `\\n`.

Comment: @Tim Actual newlines show as **`\n`**…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ｡⁠◕⁠‿⁠◕⁠｡

```
text = """
Hello, how are you?
I'm fine and you?
Same as always..
"""
print(f"{text!r}")
```

Output:

```
"\nHello, how are you?\nI'm fine and you?\nSame as always..\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `repr()` for this purpose:

```
print(repr(text))
```

This will also add quotes, and escape other characters like tabs, backspaces, etc.

Other option is to replace the newlines:

```
print(text.replace('\n', '\\n'))
```

This will escape only line breaks and no other special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that there is a "\n" at the start of the string that you want to print. You left it out in your question.

```
text = """
Hello, how are you?
I'm fine and you?
Same as always..
"""

for letter in text:
    if letter == "\n":
        print("\\n",end="")
    else:
        print(letter,end="")
```

Note that the purpose of "\\n" in the first print is to escape the "\n" character so it will print "\n" instead of printing a linebreak.